What's the best way to use Codable structs with PATCH calls?
What's the best way to use Codable structs with PATCH calls?
I guess, I need to know which properties of my struct have been updated, and then pass only those values as partial updates for the patch call.
Do I need to use didSet observers on all properies, so that I can flag which one has changed or is there a better way?
thanks
UPDATE: please check comments to the question

"Do I need to use didSet observers on all properies, so that I can flag which one has changed" That sounds about right if you just want to know which properties have changed. It won't be that tedious if you write some macros that do this for you. If I understand correctly, you want the Encodable implementation to only encode the properties that have changed, since... when? I assume there should be something like a reset method that resets all the flags?

@Sweeper Yes, all correct. What I'm asking is if  there is a better approach to deal with PATCH calls in swift? Codable are generally used to pass all data for POST calls. What if you have to deal with partial updates?

One way I thought of is to use a property wrapper like this to associate a didSet flag with the properties you are interested in:
@propertyWrapper
public struct DidSetFlag<T: Codable>: Codable {
    public var wrappedValue: T {
        didSet {
            didSet = true
        }
    }
    
    public var didSet = false
    
    public init(wrappedValue: T) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
        wrappedValue = try T(from: decoder)
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: any Encoder) throws {
        try wrappedValue.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}

Then, "hijack" KeyedEncodingContainer.encode so that if didSet is false, nothing is encoded:
extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
    mutating func encode<T: Codable>(
        _ value: DidSetFlag<T>,
        forKey key: KeyedEncodingContainer<K>.Key
    ) throws {
        if value.didSet {
            try encode(value.wrappedValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

The synthesised Codable implementation would resolve to this implementation in the extension, unless the Codable type is in a different module.
Example usage:
struct Foo: Codable {
    @DidSetFlag var foo = 0
    @DidSetFlag var bar = 0
    
    mutating func resetFlags() {
        _foo.didSet = false
        _bar.didSet = false
    }
}

var foo = Foo()
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
print(String(data: try encoder.encode(foo), encoding:. utf8)!)
foo.foo = 1
print(String(data: try encoder.encode(foo), encoding:. utf8)!)
foo.bar = 2
print(String(data: try encoder.encode(foo), encoding:. utf8)!)

/*
output:

{}
{"foo":1}
{"bar":2,"foo":1}
*/

As a bonus, here is a macro implementation to automatically add the @DidSetFlag to each property, and also generate the resetFlags method.
// declaration
@attached(memberAttribute)
@attached(member, names: named(resetFlags))
public macro EncodePropertiesWhenSet() = #externalMacro(module: "Your Module Here...", type: "EncodePropertiesWhenSet")

// implementation
enum EncodePropertiesWhenSet: MemberAttributeMacro, MemberMacro {
    static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax, providingMembersOf declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax, in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        let hasMutating = !declaration.is(ClassDeclSyntax.self)
        let function = try FunctionDeclSyntax("\(raw: hasMutating ? "mutating " : "")func resetFlags()") {
            for member in declaration.memberBlock.members {
                if let name = name(for: member.decl) {
                    "_\(raw: name).didSet = false"
                }
            }
        }
        return [DeclSyntax(function)]
    }
    
    static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax, attachedTo declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax, providingAttributesFor member: some DeclSyntaxProtocol, in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [AttributeSyntax] {
        if name(for: member) != nil {
            ["@DidSetFlag"]
        } else {
            []
        }
    }
    
    static func name(for decl: some DeclSyntaxProtocol) -> String? {
        // filter out computed properties and 'let's
        guard let varDecl = decl.as(VariableDeclSyntax.self),
              varDecl.bindingSpecifier.text == "var",
              varDecl.bindings.count == 1,
              let binding = varDecl.bindings.first,
              binding.accessorBlock == nil,
              let identifier = binding.pattern.as(IdentifierPatternSyntax.self)?.identifier.text
        else { return nil }
        return identifier
    }
}


@main
struct MyMacroPlugin: CompilerPlugin {
    let providingMacros: [Macro.Type] = [
        EncodePropertiesWhenSet.self
    ]
}

// usage:
@EncodePropertiesWhenSet
struct Foo: Codable {
    var foo = 0
    var bar = 0


